# Disable multiple size image generation for Woocommerce uploaded images only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a theme that generates 11 different sized images for every image uploaded.

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 220, 150, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-list', 491, 280, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-list-large', 614, 320, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-sidebar', 100 ,100, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-grid', 496, 290, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-tran', 480 ,250, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-tran-vertical', 328 ,480, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-video',480,150,true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-mini-list', 150 ,100, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-tran-large', 770 ,420, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-blog-vertical', 510 ,680, true);
add_image_size( 'redmag-related-image',370,247,true);
```

This is okay for the theme but it also resizes every image uploaded on Woocommerce which isn't required and takes up a lot of space.

As a temporary measure, I comment out the above code while adding images to woocommerce so it doesn't generate those images.

Can I disable the image generation for ONLY Woocommerce uploaded images?

Comment: You can try `remove_image_size`

Comment: @Dmitry I want it to be applied only for Woocommerce related images.

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes ) {

  /* Default WordPress */
  unset( $sizes[ 'thumbnail' ]);       // Remove Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
  unset( $sizes[ 'medium' ]);          // Remove Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
  unset( $sizes[ 'medium_large' ]);    // Remove Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
  unset( $sizes[ 'large' ]);           // Remove Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)

  /* With WooCommerce */
  unset( $sizes[ 'shop_thumbnail' ]);  // Remove Shop thumbnail (180 x 180 hard cropped)
  unset( $sizes[ 'shop_catalog' ]);    // Remove Shop catalog (300 x 300 hard cropped)
  unset( $sizes[ 'shop_single' ]);     // Shop single (600 x 600 hard cropped)

  return $sizes;
}

add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes' );
```

Comment: This will remove those sizes for all image types not just WC uploaded images as the author has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (not sure if anything has changed) you can't, image sizes are created when you add them via New Media, but I'm leaving that to someone better informed.

**You may try some workarounds like the one below tested and working but not checked for conflicts:**

```
// theme image size
add_image_size( '1280', 1280, 9999 );

function mlnc_remove_add_image_sizes() {
    // remove theme image size
    remove_image_size( '1280' );
    // add product image size
    add_image_size('1165', 1165, true );
}
if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'product' ) { 
  add_action('init', 'mlnc_remove_add_image_sizes');
}
```

This is the basic idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_remove_image_sizes' );
function custom_remove_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size( '1536x1536' );
    remove_image_size( '2048x2048' );
    remove_image_size( 'medium_large' );
    remove_image_size( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail' );
    remove_image_size( 'woocommerce_single' );
    remove_image_size( 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );
}
```